# Unresolved External Symbol with virtual functions

Tags: c++, qt, external, virtual, symbols

i am trying to see how virtual functions behave by using an example from design patterns with qt

here i have a header file with 2 classes defined in it:

```
#ifndef ABCLASSES_H
#define ABCLASSES_H
#include <QTextStream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A()
    {

    }
    virtual void foo(QTextStream& out);
    virtual void bar(QTextStream& out);
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void foo(QTextStream& out);
    void bar(QTextStream& out);
};

#endif // ABCLASSES_H
```

and this is the source file for those classes

```
#include "abclasses.h"

void A::foo(QTextStream& out)
{
    out << "A's foo" << endl;
    bar(out);
}

void A::bar(QTextStream& out)
{
    out << "A's bar" << endl;
}

void B::foo(QTextStream& out)
{
    out << "B's foo" << endl;
    A::bar(out);
}

void B::bar(QTextStream& out)
{
    out << "B's bar" << endl;
}
```

the problem is i can't create or use any classes from those definitions. the errors i am getting are

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   virtual void __cdecl A::foo(class QTextStream &)"
>   (?foo@A@@UEAAXAEAVQTextStream@@@Z)
>
> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   virtual void __cdecl A::bar(class QTextStream &)"
>   (?bar@A@@UEAAXAEAVQTextStream@@@Z)

<strike>since i don't have much knowledge about virtual functions. i figured it might be needed to re-declare the functions in class B but that didn't help either and added 2 more errors to my log.</strike>

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   virtual void __cdecl B::foo(class QTextStream &)"
>   (?foo@B@@UEAAXAEAVQTextStream@@@Z)
>
> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   virtual void __cdecl B::bar(class QTextStream &)"
>   (?bar@B@@UEAAXAEAVQTextStream@@@Z)

the book example just implements functions after declaring them (in the same file) and that seems to work. i am wondering why mine doesn't work and if there's a workaround

**EDIT:**
The project file uses these settings:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-08-23T11:53:16
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = untitled1
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    student.cpp \
    abclasses.cpp

HEADERS += \
    student.h \
    abclasses.h
```

i have to say that i dont have much idea when it comes to building, linking stuff but i shouldnt be needing to focus them right now for a small project. since abclases.cpp is in sources i think it is used in the building process.

student.h and .cpp are related to another tryout i had in the same project. they are not used actively right now and below is the main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
//#include "student.h"
#include "abclasses.h"

//void finish(Student& student)
//{
//    QTextStream cout(stdout);
//    cout << "The following " << student.getClassName()
//         << "has applied for graduation" << endl
//         << student.toString() << endl;
//}

int main() {
    QTextStream cout(stdout);
    B bobj;
//    A *aptr = &bobj;
//    aptr->foo(cout);
//    cout << "-------------" << endl;
//    A aobj = *aptr;
//    aobj.foo(cout);
//    cout << "-------------" << endl;
//    aobj = bobj;
//    aobj.foo(cout);
//    cout << "-------------"<< endl;
//    bobj.foo(cout);
}
```

**EDIT 2:** updated outdated error messages, updated abclasses.h

Comment: You *must* to declare the overridden functions in the `B` class.

Comment: As for your problem, are you actually *building* with the source file containing the function definitions? And I suspect you meant to make those functions in `B` `public` as well.

Comment: i tried declaring them in B class under "public:" but as i stated it just introduced me to 2 more errors. as i cant really use this editor efficiently, i am updating the question regarding the "build" part.

Comment: It sounds like abclasses.cpp isn't being compiled and/or linked.  Can you post the output of 'make'?

Comment: even though i repeatedly used clean before rebuilding the project in qt, it gave the same errors. but after manually deleting project folders, the errors are gone. thanks for pointing me in the right direction. </br> now i am going to search bug reports about qt clean method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `abclassess.cpp` file is not compiled, since the makefile is out of date compared to the `.pro` file. Right-click on the topmost project node in Qt Creator, and select `Run qmake`. Then build the project again.

This is, unfortunately, a bad interaction between Qt Creator and qmake that manifests on Windows. On that platform, qmake generates three makefiles: `Makefile`, `Makefile.release` and `Makefile.debug`. Unfortunately, only the top-level makefile has a proper dependency between the `.pro` file and the makefiles: whenever the project file changes, the makefiles will be automatically regenerated by make invoking qmake. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, since when you manually build, you invoke *nmake*/*jom* on the top `Makefile`.

But Qt Creator directly invokes `Makefile.release` or `Makefile.debug` as needed for release/debug builds, respectively. This bypasses the makefile regeneration rule present only in the base `Makefile`. It is this interaction that is the source of the bug/misbehavior that (unfortunately) affects every user of Qt Creator on Windows at the moment.

Thus you have to invoke *qmake* after each and every change to the project file - every time you add or modify a source file, for example.

There is a simple workaround - add a build step that invokes the base `Makefile` to your project configuration's build.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update the question? As you said that you have made modification in class B, please update that. Even newly faced errors.

```
private: virtual void __cdecl B::bar(class QTextStream &)" (?
```

From this error, bar function inside class B seems to be private.

Answer (score 0):

okay here is the result after digging the internet for similar problems.
the qt creator sometimes cant really tell if it is supposed to update "make" file or not and i was somewhat aware of that thus using "clean" after some big changes.
but the problem is clean or rebuild doesnt full work as i want them to. so after some suggestions, i manually deleted the build folders and now it compiles and runs normally.

Comment: It's actually not Qt Creator's job to do that - Qt Creator is not in the business of updating *anything* other than invoking qmake on the very first build of the project. The makefile itself should have a dependency on the project file, so that make can itself invoke qmake to regenerate the makefiles. Unfortunately, the way that Creator invokes the makefiles exposes a bad interaction of Creator with qmake.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but i dont understand one thing: why doesnt qt need to update qmake? If their dependency is not properly linked then they should rebuild it with every change

Comment: Ultimately, it's a bug - I don't know if it's a qmake bug or a Qt Creator bug, since in isolation both do the right thing, it's their interaction that is wrong. Someone somewhere needs to fix it. Even when it is fixed, Qt Creator will **not be directly recreating anything**. The make tool will. But right now the make tool (not `qmake`, not really anything in Qt) doesn't do that because nobody bothered telling it to... So, treat it as a bug somewhere, with a trivial workaround. Once you configure your project to work around it, you won't have that problem anymore.